# Apply changes to the HTML strings when it comes from props in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to add pre-loader icon before rendering an image in React component using the below code:

```
export default class MediaPostItem extends BaseComponent {

       public constructor(props: IMediaPostItemProperties) {
             super(props);
             this.state = {
                imageIsReady: false,
              };
        }

       componentDidMount(): void {
            const img = new Image();
            img.onload = () => this.setState({ imageIsReady: true });
            img.src = this.props.item.featuredImage?.node.sourceUrl;
       }
       
       public render(): ReactNode {
            const { item } = this.props;
            const { imageIsReady } = this.state;
            return( 
              {imageIsReady ? (
                 <img  src={item.featuredImage?.node.sourceUrl}/>
               ) : (<div> Loading</div>)
              })
       }
 }
```

Now in the other component I give a HTML strings as a real HTML in a react component using the below code:

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.content }}></div>
```

The content is including some `<img>` tags and what I need is to add a pre-loader for these `img` tags too.
I'm not sure if it's possible or not. Is there any way to apply changes to the HTML strings when it comes from props?

Comment: Can't be a definite no, since you can go the complicated way of replacing img tags and adding a className to it. Then you can use CSS and give it a background image with the Loading text.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [ReactDOM.render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render).

```
import { render } from "react-dom";

const htmlString = `
<div>
<div id="toBeReplaced"/></div>
</div>
`;

class ReplacedComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Replaced Component</h1>;
  }
}

export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <ReplacedComponent />
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById("toBeReplaced")
    );
  }

  render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }}></div>;
  }
}
```

You would need to select the `<img>` tags, with some attribute (class/id) then loop over them and render your component.